# How to apply several functions to a single pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, map-function

I am curious about if it is possible to apply several functions to a single pandas dataframe column. For example, let's say that I have three functions:

​In:

```
def foo(col):
    if 'hi' in col:
        return 'TRUE'

def bar(col):
    if 'bye' in col:
        return 'TRUE'

def baz(col):
    if 'ok' in col:
        return 'TRUE'
```

And the following dataframe:

```
dfs = pd.DataFrame({'col':['The quick hi brown fox hi jumps over the lazy dog', 
                           'The quick hi brown fox bye jumps over the lazy dog', 
                           'The NO quick brown fox ok jumps bye over the lazy dog']})
```

If I would like to apply each function to `col`, typically I will use the pandas [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function:

```
dfs['new_col1'] = dfs['col'].apply(foo)

dfs['new_col2'] = dfs['col'].apply(bar)

dfs['new_col3'] = dfs['col'].apply(baz)

dfs
```

Out:

```
    col     new_col1    new_col2    new_col3
0   The quick hi brown fox hi jumps over the lazy dog   TRUE    None    None
1   The quick hi brown fox bye jumps over the lazy...   TRUE    TRUE    None
2   The NO quick brown fox ok jumps bye over the l...   None    TRUE    TRUE
```

However, as you can see I created 3 columns. Thus, **my question is how to apply efficiently in large dataframes the above 3 functions at the same time to an specific column?**, the expected result should be:

```
    col                                                 new_col
0   The quick hi brown fox hi jumps over the lazy dog   TRUE
1   The quick hi brown fox bye jumps over the lazy...   TRUE, TRUE
2   The NO quick brown fox ok jumps bye over the l...   TRUE, TRUE
```

Note that I know that I can merge the 3 columns in a single one. Nevertheless, I would like to know if the above question is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` with `list comprehension` where filter `None` values:

```
dfs['new_col'] = dfs['col'].apply(lambda x: (', '.join([x for x in 
                                            [foo(x), bar(x), baz(x)] if x != None])))
print (dfs)
                                                 col     new_col
0  The quick hi brown fox hi jumps over the lazy dog        TRUE
1  The quick hi brown fox bye jumps over the lazy...  TRUE, TRUE
2  The NO quick brown fox ok jumps bye over the l...  TRUE, TRUE
```

Comment: It depends of your functions... The best is test it.

Comment: @J.Do no I don't think it will be faster than using the combined function. There are too many steps here: 3 function calls, .join, another if statement, and apply.

Answer (score 4):

Why not lump all functions into one giant function?

```
def oneGaintFunc(col):    
    def foo(col):
        if 'hi' in col:
            return 'TRUE'

    def bar(col):
        if 'bye' in col:
            return 'TRUE'

    def baz(col):
        if 'ok' in col:
            return 'TRUE'

    a = foo(col)
    b = bar(col)
    c = baz(col)
    return '{} {} {}'.format(a, b, c)

df['new_col'] = df['col'].apply(oneGiantFunc)
```

Comment: I also was aware about this possibility. However I was curious about the aforementioned case. Thanks

Comment: that's not the proper way but still good idea for smaller functions

Comment: @AnkitKumarNamdeo Yeah, I personally wouldn't do this but just thought this would be the most intuitive solution, honestly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can actually do it 'at the same time'. 
But nonetheless here are 2 options

**1.** assuming the functions are defined as is:

```
dfs['new_col1'] = (dfs['col'].apply(foo)&dfs['col'].apply(bar))&dfs['col'].apply(baz)
```

**2.** Redefine functions

```
def foo(aao): # all at once
    if ('hi' in col) and ('bye' in col) and ('ok' in col):
        return 'TRUE'

dfs['new_col'] = dfs['col'].apply(aao)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a lambda function, e.g.

```
lambda x: ', '.join([f(x) for f in [foo, bar, baz] if f(x)])
```

in the call to apply. Full example:

```
In : dfs['new_col'] = dfs['col'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join([f(x) for f in [foo, bar, baz] if f(x)]))

In : dfs
Out: 
                                                 col     new_col
0  The quick hi brown fox hi jumps over the lazy dog        TRUE
1  The quick hi brown fox bye jumps over the lazy...  TRUE, TRUE
2  The NO quick brown fox ok jumps bye over the l...  TRUE, TRUE
```